# how to convert List<byte[]> into byte[][] in java

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions, jedis

I wanna use a method of Jedis client which supports varargs:

```
hMGet(byte[] key, byte[]... fields)
```

Now. I have built the `key` with `String`, `fields` which type is `List<byte[]>` and pass it into hMGet method in this way:

```
hMGet(key.getBytes(), fields.toArray(new byte[][fields.size()]))
```

But grammar error occurs. How to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
list.toArray(new byte[0][0]);
```

or

```
list.toArray(new byte[list.size()][]);
```

Whenever you create an array you should indicate it's size, or provide data:

```
String[] a = new String[0];  <- size 0 
String[] b = new String[]{};  <- empty, size 0
String[] c = new String[]{"a", "b"};  <- size 2
```

In your case, you are indicating size in the wrong place (not in the initial array, which contains other arrays)

> new **byte[]**[fields.size()]

correct is :

> new **byte[fields.size()]**[]

Comment: Oh, guy. You save my day - from a hot ass locates in a crowded office and cannot think, even breath. Really thanks.